# How to troubleshoot connection error from windows to unix?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, connection, timeout

Sidenote: I am still trying to fix [this issue](https://serverfault.com/q/697096/197301).

I have a ubuntu server running bind on 192.168.0.2, listening to :53

```
# netstat -tulpn //output shortened
tcp 0 0 192.168.0.2:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3795/named
```

Running `dig` on that machine (`dig google.de @localhost`) works just fine.

There is another machine (Win7) on 192.168.0.10. However, running lookups there always times out:

```
> dig.exe google.de @192.168.0.2 +trace +all //again shortened output
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Trying to telnet to 192.168.0.2 from the windows machine also fails on all ports I have tried (53 and 80).

Also, trying to SSH in via Putty also times out.

The issues started after updating Ubuntu to 14.04.2 yesterday. There is no Firewall on Windows or the router. Nothing changed except the updated Ubuntu machine.

**How can I further troubleshoot the problem?**

Comment: Would the downvoter care to tell me why, so I maybe can improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-server-disable-firewall/

The problem was *ufw*, which seems to have been enabled with the update. Running `ufw disable` fixed the problem.